# Swift 3.0 xCode 8 Migration pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, migration

i have some problems with xCode 8.

1. I have converted my .xCodeproject in swift 3.0 sintax
2. i Have installed all cocoapods compatible with swift 3.0

[Here my pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Iec.png)

So every pod require the legacy swift version OR xCode return ditto error OR xCode return some error about the pods sintax. Please help me.

Comment: What version of cocoa pods are you using because I think they fixed that legacy swift thing in the latest beta

Comment: i use the latest beta cocoapods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove the pods requiring legacy swift version manually changed to YES task, add this script to your podfile.  It will go through your pods and set it to use the 3.0 version

```
 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = "3.0"
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: please change "3.0" to '3.0' may be correct for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.latest xcode 8

2.if already pod file created in your project so then u do this command

```
open -e podfile
```

and then

```
    use_frameworks!

    target '<your project name>' do
        pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
        //your all pod put here above end
    end
```